# What does the random seed influence in transformers?

Tags: transformer

I've been doing some experiments with setting different seeds on transformer training, and wanted to understand why I see so much variance.

Am I correct in thinking the random seed only influences two things when transformer training:

- The random sorting of the training data;
- Which connections get removed by dropout.

Oh, and the initial value of the randomly-initialized weights.

If so, that implies there is no stochastic element at all when using the model for inference?

Maybe my question would be better phrased as: what functions use randomness, so I can search a codebase for them, and confirm where they are used?

(I'm mainly looking at PyTorch implementations such as fairseq and huggingface; but I am assuming tensorflow implementations handle random numbers the same way.)

Comment: Please, consider marking the answer as correct or commenting on what makes you think it is not.

Comment: @noe Thanks for the nudge. I had wanted to run a test of trying to confirm I get repeatable results if I drop dropout, and don't sort training data, but might be a while before I get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, both regarding the stochastic elements at training time (weight initialization, training data ordering, dropout) and that there are no inherent stochastic elements at inference time **in the model itself**.

Now, assuming we are talking about either a full transformer with encoder and decoder (e.g. for machine translation, like the original formulation) or a mere transformer decoder (e.g. a *causal* language model like GPT-3):
note that the model itself does not define the decoding strategy (i.e. how to generate tokens), so you can choose to use a deterministic strategy (e.g. greedy decoding, beam search) or to **use a stochastic decoding strategy** (e.g. normal sampling from the output multinomial distribution, nucleus sampling, top-k sampling).

Also, there are some practical nuances to take into account, like some non-deterministic behaviors of specific implementations in CUDA (see [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html)).